# How to Check if Linux File System is Hanging in Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filesystems

I am trying to write a shell script in bash to alert me if my filesystem works or not. So I am using `cd` to a filesystem and then check the exit status to see if it worked or not. If exit status is 1 then there was an error message so there's something wrong with the filesystem, so it should alert me or do something.

Here's what I tried doing but this only works if the file system returns back an error message if i try to `cd` to it. But let's say the filesystem is hanging so the command will hang. Hence I can't even check the exit status of the command to see if it failed or successded. Any idea how I can go about this?

```
cd /home/filesystem1
status=$(echo $?)
if [[ $status == 1 ]]
   then
    echo "filesystem1 is down" > $message
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking if the filesystem is mounted instead of trying to `cd` into it?

`grep "folder_name" /proc/mounts` will return 0 if the folder exists, 1 otherwise

Other option would be check the filesystems on your box:
`cat /proc/filesystems`. 
The content of this file is built in real time (/proc), so when it's read it reflects the actual current status

Comment: Thanks @Vinny for the suggestion. Your answer seems more sensible. How about if the filesystem returns a "stale file handle" error message, would it should if i `grep` for it from /proc/mounts?

Comment: `/proc/mounts` would show only active mounts. You can do some trial and error and see what happens if you remove the directory while mounted (I'm not sure what the behavior would be)

Comment: Another check you can do is `ls -l <folder>` to check if it exists, or catching the folder's inode using `ls -id <folder>` and check if it was changed. In case it was deleted you would get an error

Comment: Thanks again @Vinny. How about if I use `timeout 10 ls /filesystem1` would this be a good approach?

Comment: @Dr.Bake sounds like a good idea. If you found my answer useful, please kindly consider upvoting and accepting it, thanks

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot for your great help :) I ended up doing `timeout 10 ls /filesystem` and then check the exit status of that command by using `echo $?` and if it was not 0, then there's a problem. But your answer was a great help so I accepted it as the answer. Thanks again :)